# Google cloud sdks doesn't start preview for Docker image Mac OS

Tags: google-app-engine, go, docker, gcloud, revel

My app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
vm: true
api_version: 1
health_check:
  enable_health_check: False
```

Dockerfile

```
# Use the official go docker image built on debian.
FROM golang:1.5.1

# Grab the source code and add it to the workspace.
ADD . /go/

# Install revel and the revel CLI.
RUN go get github.com/revel/revel
RUN go get github.com/revel/cmd/revel

# Use the revel CLI to start up our application.
ENTRYPOINT revel run 4quorum-appengine dev 8080

# Open up the port where the app is running.
EXPOSE 8080
```

I was working through this article
http://jbeckwith.com/2015/05/08/docker-revel-appengine/

### Preview

I am trying to preview it:

```
gcloud preview app run app.yaml --custom-entrypoint "revel run 4quorum-appengine dev 8080"
WARNING: The `app run` command is deprecated and will soon be removed.

Please use dev_appserver.py (in the same directory as the `gcloud` command) instead.
Module [default] found in file     [/Users/802619/Projects/src/4quorum_root/app.yaml]
INFO: Looking for the Dockerfile in     /Users/802619/Projects/src/4quorum_root
INFO: Using Dockerfile found in /Users/802619/Projects/src/4quorum_root
INFO     2015-11-06 18:03:44,226 application_configuration.py:399] No version specified. Generated version id: 20151106t180344
INFO     2015-11-06 18:03:44,226 devappserver2.py:763] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2015-11-06 18:03:44,266 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:62780
INFO     2015-11-06 18:03:44,272 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2015-11-06 18:03:44,277 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2015-11-06 18:03:44,282 instance.py:280] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The same thing if trying dev_appserver.py

### Deploy

Deploy also doesn't work. Fails because of timeout.

```
gcloud preview app deploy ./app.yaml
WARNING: Soon, deployments will set the deployed version to receive all traffic by
```

default.

```
To keep the current behavior (where new deployments do not receive any traffic),
use the `--no-promote` flag or run the following command:

  $ gcloud config set app/promote_by_default false

 To adopt the new behavior early, use the `--promote` flag or run the     following
command:

  $ gcloud config set app/promote_by_default true

  Either passing one of the new flags or setting one of these properties will
```

silence this message.

```
 You are about to deploy the following modules:
 - vaulted-gift-112113/default (from   [/Users/802619/Projects/src/4quorum_root/app.yaml])
       Deployed URL: [https://20151106t204027-dot-vaulted-gift-      112113.appspot.com]
 (add --promote if you also want to make this module available from
 [https://vaulted-gift-112113.appspot.com])

Beginning deployment...
Verifying that Managed VMs are enabled and ready.

Provisioning remote build service.
Copying certificates for secure access. You may be prompted to create an SSH keypair.
Building and pushing image for module [default]
Saving [.dockerignore] to [/Users/802619/Projects/src/4quorum_root].
----------------------------- DOCKER BUILD OUTPUT ------------------------------
Step 0 : FROM golang:1.5.1
---> f6271e8f3723
Step 1 : ADD . /go/
---> 94fafc5e8a30
Removing intermediate container cfbe197f6e93
Step 2 : RUN go get github.com/revel/revel
---> Running in d7ad8c923144
---> b65877cf3049
Removing intermediate container d7ad8c923144
Step 3 : RUN go get github.com/revel/cmd/revel
---> Running in 2a9b3320ce47
---> 428defd008f3
Removing intermediate container 2a9b3320ce47
Step 4 : ENTRYPOINT revel run 4quorum-appengine dev 8080
---> Running in 8b9e38ec69ec
---> 3749ee8a6636
Removing intermediate container 8b9e38ec69ec
Step 5 : EXPOSE 8080
---> Running in a0e6c66b56c8
---> dafff62b9643
Removing intermediate container a0e6c66b56c8
Successfully built dafff62b9643
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Copying files to Google Cloud Storage...
Synchronizing files to [gs://staging.vaulted-gift-112113.appspot.com/].
Updating module [default]...|Deleted      [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/vaulted-gift-  112113/zones/us-central1-f/instances/gae-builder-vm-20151106t204027].
 Updating module [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out creating VMs.
```

About to drop this.

Comment: *ck google and google app engine. I moved to heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved to heroku. Google App Engine is not ready yet.